# Working on a Queue of Students made out of a double linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote this function to pop and print out 3 students at a time, and to keep doing it until the queue is empty. For some reason, it stops after only printing 3 students. Any ideas as to why? Front is a pointer to the front of my list, and back is a pointer to the back. The list is non circular.

```
void pop_front()
    {
        int num = 0;
            string value;
            while(front != NULL)
            {
                while(num<3)
                {
                    Node *temp = front;
                    if(front->next)
                    {   value = front->name;
                        front = front->next;
                        front->prev = NULL;
                        size--;
                        delete temp;
                        cout<<value<<", ";
                        num++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                    if(front->next == NULL)
                    {
                        value=front->name;
                        front = NULL;
                        back = NULL;
                        delete temp;
                        size--;
                        cout<<" The last student in this priority Queue list is:  "<<value<<endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            return;
    }
```

Comment: Does it print "The last student in this priority Queue list is:"..? What's the output?

Comment: Ok, when I have 3 students in my list, It will enter the last if loop and print out " The last student....." then my program will crash.

Comment: @user2130537: For the 3-student case, this probably happens because if you enter the second if-block, num will still be 3 when the inner loop block finishes, restarts, and then you're in an infinite loop. To fix it, return after printing "The last student..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset `num` to 0 within the `while(front != NULL)` loop, not outside it.